# How to include html files like include in php?

Tags: php, html, file, header, include

How can we include files inside html, like how we usually include files in Php.

```
<?php include "nav.php";?>
```

Comment: No you can't include file inside html

Comment: are you looking for iframe? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: You can include files into html, only if you tell the server to treat html as PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#container").load('somepage.html');
```

Learn more about the `load` function and what more you can do with it in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ajax, see [JQuery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/), example:

```
<div id="moreData"></div>
$( "#moreData" ).load( "otherPage.html" );
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use jQuery.

```
<html> 
 <head> 
  <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
      $(function(){
      $("#includeCont").load("file.html"); 
      });
    </script> 
  </head> 

 <body> 
  <div id="includeCont"></div>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ifrmae

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Or use Frameset

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
  <frame src="http://www.w3schools.com/frame_a.php">
  <frame src="http://www.w3schools.com/frame_b.php">
  <frame src="http://www.w3schools.com/frame_c.php">
</frameset>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a round about method using http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html

Server Side includes

E.g `<!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->`

Comment: Clever solution, though this maybe won't work on shared hosting.

Comment: Yes correct. The server needs to be configured first to accept SSI.

Comment: Side note: The file needs to have the `.shtml` extension in order for this to work. This needs to be pointed out in your answer, and not just a link for someone to visit.

Comment: @Fred -ii Regarding the Side note. I guess you should not write wrong information here. Please read the link Carefully. Any type of file can be configured to use SSI. Not only .shtml. `AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml`

Comment: Yeah I know that, and I was going to mention that before you commented, but what's the point in doing that, when the OP can just as well treat html as PHP? ;-)

Comment: Plus, `.shtml` files don't have as much functionality as PHP files, so it's better to treat html as PHP, instead of SSI.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with webpack and html-webpack-plugin.
This is index.html. You can create multiple files.

like this.

```
<%= require('html-loader!./views/partial/nav.html') %>
```

and here's more.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Your Site Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <%= require('html-loader!./views/partial/nav.html') %>

    <main id="mainDiv">
      <!-- Section Banner -->
      <%= require('html-loader!./views/partial/index/section-banner.html') %>

      <!-- Section Services -->
      <%= require('html-loader!./views/partial/index/section-services.html') %>

      <!-- Section About us -->
      <%= require('html-loader!./views/partial/index/section-aboutus.html') %>

      <!-- Section Call To Action -->
      <%= require('html-loader!./views/partial/index/section-call-to-action.html') %>

      <!-- Section Footer -->
      <%= require('html-loader!./views/partial/footer.html') %>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```